# How can I avoid an IllegalStateException if I need to add a Fragment in onNewIntent() or after a run-time change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I'm well aware of what an IllegalStateException is and why it happens when you are trying to commit FragmentTransactions after instance state has been saved. I've read through most of the popular Stackoverflow questions on the subject as well as "[The Blog Post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html)."

I have a particular scenario in which I've created a Fragment to display a custom progress spinner while the app is waiting for some search results to come in. So my search Activity is running in singleTop mode and relies on `onNewIntent()` to perform the search and display the spinner. This all works fine, but fails when run-time changes come in (like orientation changes). I'll get an IllegalStateException if I try removing the progress spinner Fragment after an orientation change, or when adding the spinner after a voice search. My setup looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH)) {
        performSearch(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
    } 
}
```

The `performSearch()` method sends the request to my server and then adds the progress spinner Fragment like this...

```
private void showProgressSpinner() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_fade_in, R.anim.fragment_fade_out);
    ProgressFragment spinner = ProgressFragment.newInstance();
    transaction.add(R.id.searchContainer, spinner, "spinner");
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Then when the search results come in through an asynchronous callback, I remove the progress spinner Fragment like this...

```
private void dismissProgressSpinner() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_fade_in, R.anim.fragment_fade_out);
    ProgressFragment spinner = (ProgressFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("spinner");
    if(spinner != null) {
        transaction.remove(spinner);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```

If an orientation change comes in while the progress spinner Fragment is being displayed, I get the IllegalStateException when the search results return and I try to remove the spinner Fragment. According to [Alex Lockwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/844882/alex-lockwood), putting the FragmentTransaction in `onPostResume()` can help, since you are guaranteed to have the state restored by then. This indeed works, but I need to remove the Fragment in my asynchronous callback from the search results, not when the Activity resumes.

So my question is, how can I commit this Fragment transaction after a state change, but within my async callback? I've tried using `commitAllowingStateLoss()` but I still get the exception because my `spinner` Fragment is still referencing the old destroyed Activity. What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried using commitAllowingStateLoss() but I still get the exception because my spinner Fragment is still referencing the old destroyed Activity.

your fragment was recreated after config change, ie. after user have rotated screen - your spinner fragment will be destroyed and recreated, and after onAttach it will reference new activity instance. Also all of this process is done by android on UI thread in single message, so there is no chance that your async operation callback (which should execute also on UI thread) gets executed in the middle.

I assume here you are not creating some local reference to activity inside ProgressFragment.

You could write additional logic that would make sure your commit is called in valid moment. ie. in your activity onStart set some static boolean allowCommit to true, and in onPause set it to false. Also add some static variable, searchWasFinished, and in your async callback check if allowCommit is true if so then immediately remove spinner, if not then only set searchWasFinished to true. Inside your Activity.onStart check if searchWasFinished==true and if so then remove fragment with commit. This is just an idea, probably more logic would have to be put in it.

Comment: I actually am creating a local reference to activity inside ProgressFragment. I get it from `onAttach()` and use it to load my rotate animation. Is this a problem? Also, as for your "instance variables" suggestion, yeah that's kind of what I've been resorting to, but it just makes everything so messy and complex...I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: No - I dont think so, I was thinking if you might have leaked an Activity reference, but that would be possible only if your fragment was retained and you have stored activity's reference as class variable. I think you should be able to use commitAllowingStateLoss in your scenerio. Other solutions are rather messy.

Comment: When I use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` it solves some of the issues (such as the state loss that happened on voice search), but on orientation change, I still get the error when `dismissProgressSpinner()` is called, but the error changes to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed` -- This has me pretty confused, because I don't know why there would be a reference to an old Activity when this is called well after `onResume()` is finished loading the saved state.

Comment: check if maybe this is because of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601

Comment: Yeah I was just reading about that. I think that's only for nested Fragments. I only have the one Fragment that gets added to an Activity.

Comment: I'm going to give you the accepted answer, because ultimately I ended up having to use a bunch of state variables to just track all the times the fragment should be visible or hidden. Thanks for your help and input.